# Using 'ping' command on Windows CMD, but packet was lost

Tags: web, networking, command-line, ping

Today I learned about, basic structure of packet switch mechanism. So I tried a kind of test. Currently I am using Windows, so I opened command prompt, and type **ping naver.com**, which means send a packet to website **https://m.naver.com/**.
Okay and the result is, **packet: sent=4, received=0, loss=4 (100% loss). And I heard on some website that, if I had my packet loss on specific website, this means, there are problems on network communication between my computer and the website server.
But, When I get into the website after **ping test**, there is nothing wrong on website.

So my Question is this.

1. the meaning of packet loss is the malfunction of network between host and server, but, in my case, it seems to be nothing wrong...
   Why is it???

Answer (score 1):

It can simply mean that their server has been configured to not respond to ping. In this case, you are still able to access it through a browser.

Comment: Yes, it can be interpreted as a security related move. This way, automated network scanners that search for vulnerabilities have a harder time finding accessible sites.